# Add image src to array

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, smarty

I'm using this loop for display images (using smarty)

```
{foreach from=$gallery item=image key=KEY}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 smallImage">
        <img ng-click="bigImage('/files/galleries/{$image.galleryId}/{$image.name}_full.jpg')" data-width="{$image.width}" data-height="{$image.height}" class="galleryImage" src="/files/galleries/{$image.galleryId}/{$image.name}_full.jpg" /><br />
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

And what I want to do is add the `{$image.name}` variable into an array in my angular controller. How do I do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using ngRepeat -  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat?

Comment: Mixing server code and client code ? You're doing it wrong. Make a choice : angular or smarty to generate your template ?

Comment: I just realized that now, this is the project I'm learning Angular with :P, changed it to ng-repeat now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `$gallery` to Angular by using one of those approaches:

1. use Ajax get data
2. ng-init
3. javascript global variable

And then use `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 smallImage" ng-repeat="image in gallery">
    <img ng-click="..." ng-src="...."><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Angular ng-repeat rather than smarty.